# ERROR ngx-daterangepicker-material An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ngx-daterangepicker-material

Can you help me out with this error? this my package.json error
I keep getting this error:

ERROR in node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts(59,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

```
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-angular-calendars": "^17.4.51",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.35",
    "acorn": "^6.4.1",
    "angular-hammer": "^2.2.0",
    "angular-svg-icon": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "mat-range-datepicker": "^1.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^2.3.1",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.9.20",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.2.1",
    "ngx-drag-scroll": "^8.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "pretty-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.11.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
``
thank you
```

Comment: I am getting same issue when I install ngx-chips for Tag npm. Now I can not also compile and getting same issue

Answer (score 16):

For metronic-angular 6.1.8, I spent 8 hours, but I solved.

- removed package-lock.json
- removed node_modules folder
- npm install

if you execute `ng serve` received TS1086 error, don't worry...

now launch:

- npm i ngx-daterangepicker-material@2.2.0
- npm i moment@2.18.1

relaunch `ng serve enjoy! ;)

the first solution solved the development part, but there are problems during the deployment. The final solution is:

- removed package-lock.json
- removed node_modules folder
- in package.json remove (^) on library ngx-daterangepicker-material ("ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.1.11" -> "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.1.11")
- increase version moment from ^2.24.0 to 2.25.3 (remove ^, "moment": "^2.24.0" -> "moment": "2.25.3",

Now working all... both ng serve and yarn build. ;)

Comment: I cannot believe that the answer I was looking for is from you Pasquale! It's incredible to meet here on a randomly choosen answer on stackoverflow!
Anyway it worked for me, thanks a lot and hope to hear from you soon!

Comment: This answer saves me from hours and hours and hours of searching!

Answer (score 9):

I solved the issue by following 2 steps

1. First remove `"ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.2.1"` from `package.json`
2. Run `npm i ngx-daterangepicker-material@2.2.0`
3. "ng serve"

It will compile successfully

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved the issue by following steps

1. First, remove the node_modules folder from your project folder
2. In your package.json replace above version for ngx-daterangepicker-material from
   2.2.1 to 2.1.9, like

remove -> "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.2.1",

add ->  "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.1.9",

3. Run npm install command in terminal and then compile

It will compile successfully

Comment: Weird that this solves the issue. For me this actually solved this issue as well but I can not explain how...

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue, we will have to check the `angular version` used in your project. Based on the angular version we have to update the `ngx-daterangepicker-material` libray in the `package.json`.

Check the below to find suitable library version for your angular project:

Versions:

```
Angular      ngx-daterangepicker-material
>=9.0.0      v2.3.x and v3.x
<9.0.0       v2.2.x and below
```

Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material

Run the below comment for prod build if you face `javascript heap out of memory` issue in normal `"ng --prod"`:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build client --prod
```

Comment: change the version but the problem persist

Comment: Please do "npm install" once done with package.json changes and check if the angular version is less than 9 use the "ngx-daterangepicker-material" version 2.2.0 and check with the build command.

Comment: the answer for solve my problem it´s up, in the explication pasquale carucci. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have the same problem, but i try change version, but doesn't work

```
{
"name": "metronic-angular",
"version": "6.1.8",
"description": "Packages used by Angular",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "rtl": "webpack"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^9.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.11.1", // change version but the problem persist
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.6.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the proposed solutions above, they didn't solve the issue for me.
However, I solved this issue by simply changing the package version:

"ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.1.9"

Then
 - removing node_modules folder
 - npm install
 - ng serve works
 - ng build --prod --aot=true also works

Answer (score 0):

1. First remove "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.2.1" from package.json
2. Run "npm i ngx-daterangepicker-material@2.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

First remove "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.2.1" from package.json

Run "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "2.2.0"

If there is this sign ^ please uninstall it then try again npm install.
**^** this mark upper version install