# daterangepicker.component.d.ts: error An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

My englisg it's very poor, i am working metronic,angular material y ng bootstrapt ,but i have this problem 
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts(59,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts(62,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.component.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.directive.d.ts(55,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.directive.d.ts(56,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.directive.d.ts(59,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.directive.d.ts(60,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.directive.d.ts(62,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/daterangepicker.directive.d.ts(63,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
node_modules/ngx-daterangepicker-material/locale.service.d.ts(5,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
My **package.json**

```
{
"name": "metronic-angular",
"version": "6.1.8",
"description": "Packages used by Angular",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json",
    "rtl": "webpack"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.5",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/entity": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.6.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.8.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "chartist": "^0.11.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.6.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^9.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-inline-svg": "^9.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.2.4",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^12.3.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.1.11",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^3.0.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-permissions": "^7.0.3",
    "object-path": "^0.11.4",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "^1.4.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "socicon": "^3.0.5",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.22",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^8.6.0",
    "@types/chartist": "^0.9.46",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.24",
    "@types/object-path": "^0.11.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-messages": "^2.0.4",
    "webpack-rtl-plugin": "^2.0.0"
}
```

}
node -v
v12.16.3
npm -v
6.14.4
my angulaar version
Angular CLI: 9.1.4
Node: 12.16.3
OS: linux x64

```
Angular: 
... 
Ivy Workspace: 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.4
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.4
@schematics/angular          9.1.4
@schematics/update           0.901.4
rxjs                         6.5.4
```

i tried change version 
ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.1.11" => 2.1.9
but doesn't work.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248058/error-ngx-daterangepicker-material-an-accessor-cannot-be-declared-in-an-ambient

Comment: or try just try this `npm i -D ngx-daterangepicker-material@2.2.0`

Answer (score 3):

For `metronic-angular 6.1.8`, I spent 8 hours, but I solved.

```
rm package-lock.json
rm -r node_modules
npm install
```

when you execute `ng serve` and received `TS1086 error`

try below and relaunch again:

```
npm i ngx-daterangepicker-material@2.2.0
npm i moment@2.18.1
```

relaunch `ng serve`

Comment: you should try https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-daterangepicker-material-dayjs